# Sitecore 10.1 Path Analyzer Error

Tags: xdb, xconnect, path-analyzer

We recently upgraded from Sitecore 8 to Sitecore 10.1 and have encountered an error in Path Analyzer. The error message is:

```
Message: Could not load type 'Sitecore.ContentTesting.Rules.Conditions.EntryPageCondition' from assembly 'Sitecore.ContentTesting'.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.ContentTreePredicateDescriptorLocator.GetDescriptor(Guid id)


 464 08:48:58 ERROR [Path Analyzer] Error during aggregation.
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.PredicateDescriptorException
Message: No known predicate type could be determined from 'Sitecore.ContentTesting.Rules.Conditions.EntryPageCondition,Sitecore.ContentTesting' specified in the definition item (Id = '9bd1f746-b5df-4fe3-a1f8-af6dfb660333', db = 'master') : Could not load type 'Sitecore.ContentTesting.Rules.Conditions.EntryPageCondition' from assembly 'Sitecore.ContentTesting'.
Source: Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.xMgmt
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.ContentTreePredicateDescriptorLocator.GetDescriptor(Guid id)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.ConditionXmlNodeConverter.LookupType(Guid descriptorId)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.ConditionXmlNodeConverter.ConvertNodeInternal(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.BaseXmlRuleNodeConverter`1.Convert(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement node)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.AndXmlNodeConverter.ConvertNodeInternal(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.BaseXmlRuleNodeConverter`1.Convert(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement node)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.TreeConverter.TreeConverter`2.Convert(TFromNode treeRoot)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.RuleXmlConverter.CreateRule(XElement ruleElement)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.RulesBuilder.BuildXmlRules(String rulesXml)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.RulesBuilder.BuildRules(String rulesXml)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.RulesValidator.ValidateRule(Interaction interaction, String rulesXml, ConditionParameters parameters)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeBuilder.IsApplicable(Interaction interaction, String rulesXml, ConditionParameters conditionParameters)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeBuilder.Build(Interaction interaction)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.AggregationContextCollector.Collect(Interaction interaction)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.TreeAggregator.Aggregate(ItemBatch`1 batch)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
```

The error is complaining about the type `Sitecore.ContentTesting.Rules.Conditions.EntryPageCondition` which exists in the assembly `Sitecore.ContentTesting`.

I have tried the following steps to get rid of the error.

- Deleted from TreeDefinitions
- Redeployed all Path Analyzer Map definitions by visiting the tool - /sitecore/admin/pathanalyzer.aspx
- Clicked "Deploy all maps that are not deployed" in the Maps Manager section
- Clicked "Rebuild" in the Historic Map Rebuild section
- Cleared all tables in the RefData database
- Redeployed all Marketing Definitions
- Rebuild the xDB index in Solr
- Rebuild the reporting database
- Rebuild all Solr indexes
- Reset the IIS pool multiple times

Although the above steps have allowed me to show data being recorded in the xDB correctly, Path Analyzer errors continue to occur.

[image]

I have also checked the assembly. It has a EntryPageConditions class.

[image]

Can someone suggest potential solutions to resolve it? Thank you.

Comment: Did you stop all content tests?

Comment: @SitecorePro do you mean turning off content testing like this <setting name="ContentTesting.AutomaticContentTesting.Enabled" value="false" />
?

Comment: Here is the guide on how to stop tests 
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/91/sitecore-experience-platform/cancel-active-tests.html

Comment: @SitecorePro there are no active tests

Comment: check this out, it may not be directly related but might help
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0703360

Comment: @SitecorePro this is for Sitecore 9 and I am using Sitecore 10?

Comment: @SitecorePro only "Entry Page" rule item is found in Sitecore 10.1 which cannot be deleted. I am getting the error "Some of selected items are in resources and cannot be deleted."

Comment: Did you try deploying marketing definitions?

Comment: yeah i did. I repeated all the steps mentioned again in the question except for Rebuilding reporting database @SitecorePro

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you have upgraded the database, but not deployed the latest sitecore DLLS.

If you look at the latest v8 release - **Sitecore Experience Platform 8.0 Update-6**. The Sitecore.ContentTesting assembly doesnt contain the **EntryPageCondition** Class.

[image: Sitecore Experience Platform 8.0 Update-6 - sitecore.contenttesting.dll]

Whereas the equivalent in **Sitecore Experience Platform 10.1 Update-2** has the class defined.
[image: Sitecore Experience Platform 10.1 Update-2 - Sitecore.Contenttesting.dll]

Please review the bin folder on your sitecore installation. Check the properties of the Sitecore.ContentTesting.dll and ensure you are running ***Assembly: Sitecore.ContentTesting, Version=17.0.0.0***

**UPDATE**

Further suggestions if DLLs updated.

- Check solution (and .csproj files) for any old references that might somehow be lookng for old version of the file.
- Also double check all other sitecore references are updated to 10.1
- Ensure all projects correctly updated to run on .net 4.8
- If you using processing server confirm DLLs have been successfully update there too.
- Backup Sitecore DLLs then remove all and replace with DLLs from a clean install

Comment: thanks for the reply. Dll was the first thing I checked to make sure that the EntryPageConditions class exist in the Sitecore.ContentTesting API. I am using version 17.0.2. The assembly is correct and It has the required class. I have now updated my question.

Comment: thanks owais - please see update